# Linux Compile Error of radiation transport codes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am compiling a radiation transport code built by NRC. Before install the programe i need to compile Linux platform codes. I Have managed to install most of required libraries and manged so far, and when i execute 
 make '-f Makefile.Linux' it compiled up to certain extent and now it gave a compile error, can somebody explain what causes this compile error ( i am not Linux expert)[image: Please see the compile error]
Hope someone can help me, I can provide additional information if required.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: Off-topic. You need to install `gfortran` (or `g77`) and use it (probably by *editing* a few lines in your `Makefile.Linux` ...). You'll also need to install many other software (e.g. libraries). You probably won't be able to compile your thing without help, or without investing many days in learning more about Linux.

Comment: Can you please let me know in which topic should i post it, I have already install gFORTRAN and other libraries, this comes with other main software and it work fine

Comment: You might ask on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). Don't use screenshots when asking (show the command you have typed, and their answer, as code text with four spaces). And do spend several days reading stuff (e.g. some Linux book, and something about [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)s...). Ask someone from the computer science department of your university.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I ll do that